# Change the color of one link when one particular image of my slideshow is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to highlight (change the color) my navigationlinks seperately for each individual picture that shows up in my slideshow.

(e.g.: 3 different slideshow pictures that should separately change the color of each navigationlink. If Picture "A" is shown the navigationlink "1" should change its color to black - if picture "B" is shown it should change the navigationlink "2" to the color black and the color of navigationlink "1" to grey ... and so on.)

This is an example of my navigation:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="link_one" href="photographer_one.html">Pothographer One</a></li>
    <li><a id="link_two" href="photographer_two.html">Pothographer Two</a></li>
    <li><a id="link_three" href="photographer_three.html">Pothographer Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm working with this [slideshow](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/background-slideshow/) and here is my example in html:

```
<ul id="cbp-bislideshow" class="cbp-bislideshow">
  <li id="image_one"><img src="image_one.jpg" width="1920" height="1080" alt="image_one"/></li>
  <li id="image_two"><img src="image_two.jpg" width="1920" height="1080" alt="image_two"/></li>
  <li id="image_three"><img src="image_three.jpg" width="1920" height="1080" alt="image_three"/></li>
</ul>
```

My javascript knowledge is very limited. I've tried to add an class to the current image and remove it also when the next one shows up. This one works fine.

But how is it possible to create an interaction between the slideshow and the navigation?

I'm very thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a quick scan of that plugin's code, it looks like you would have to modify the Javascript yourself.

Some slideshows let you configure a callback that is called each time there is a slide transition. You could modify the slideshow to do that. Insert code so that, whenever there was a transition, it calls a separate function, passing the new slide information.

In this separate function, you could then do what you wanted. For example, change a class name or the style of another element.

Comment: Could you please help me to write the function?

Comment: It's better if you work out the details yourself, but some hints; (1) The function "navigate" changes the image. You could make a call to your own function at the end of it passing $newItem as a parameters. The function would then look at some aspect of $newItem like id to decide about what to do; (2) In your function you can get the link using an ID and change the text color using $('#idoflink').css('color', '#whatever').